# Windows Subsystem Linux sed commando not working through bat file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the linux subsystem installed and when I run the ubuntu app or login to the subsystem console via `wsl` or `bash` I can run the following command without any problems:

```
sed -i 's/.*loginscreen.username.*/loginscreen.username={{USERNAME}}/' /mnt/c/Users/{{USER}}/.runelite/profiles/{{PROFILE}}/settings.properties
```

However, when I create a .bat file with the following content it does give me an error:

```
@ECHO OFF
bash -c sed -i 's/.*loginscreen.username.*/loginscreen.username={{USERNAME}}/' /mnt/c/Users/{{USER}}/.runelite/profiles/{{PROFILE}}/settings.properties
PAUSE
```

I also tried using `wsl {{COMMAND}}` in the bat script but that has the same outcome.

```
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
      --debug
                 annotate program execution
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed
  -f script-file, --file=script-file
                 add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
  --follow-symlinks
                 follow symlinks when processing in place
  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
  -l N, --line-length=N
                 specify the desired line-wrap length for the `l' command
  --posix
                 disable all GNU extensions.
  -E, -r, --regexp-extended
                 use extended regular expressions in the script
                 (for portability use POSIX -E).
  -s, --separate
                 consider files as separate rather than as a single,
                 continuous long stream.
      --sandbox
                 operate in sandbox mode (disable e/r/w commands).
  -u, --unbuffered
                 load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush
                 the output buffers more often
  -z, --null-data
                 separate lines by NUL characters
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

If no -e, --expression, -f, or --file option is given, then the first
non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret.  All
remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are
specified, then the standard input is read.

GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
```

Basically I want to have a bat file which changes text in a file and after that execute an executable.
I tried to use sed to change the text but that didn't work.
How do I have to change my .bat file to make the script change the text using sed or any other method?

sed version: 4.7

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: I think you need to quote the command, because otherwise all the parameters following sed are passed to bash instead of sed and you effectively run sed without any parameters. `bash -c "sed -i 's/.*loginscreen.username.*/loginscreen.username={{USERNAME}}/' /mnt/c/Users/{{USER}}/.runelite/profiles/{{PROFILE}}/settings.properties"`

Comment: Please do not give slabs of text that are just a copy-pasted man page.

Comment: @DerMaddi's suggestion will work, but I recommend `wsl -e /bin/bash -c "sed -i 's/.*loginscreen.username.*/loginscreen.username={{USERNAME}}/' /mnt/c/Users/{{USER}}/.runelite/profiles/{{PROFILE}}/settings.properties"`.  WSL's `bash` command is considered a ["historical command"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#additional-commands) which has been replaced by `wsl.exe`.  The `wsl` command is much more flexible and robust.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the command with `wsl` rather than `bash` and quote the command:

```sh
wsl -e /bin/bash -c "sed -i 's/.*loginscreen.username.*/loginscreen.username={{USERNAME}}/' /mnt/c/Users/{{USER}}/.runelite/profiles/{{PROFILE}}/settings.properties"
```